# VBA Excel Creating Sparkline

Tags: excel, vba

Creating Sparkline in a merged cell referenced as "Section3". The Data I want to reference for the Sparkline chart is located in a named field "TBLCOL3".

```
<Sub Macro14()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim rng4 As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
i = 3

Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("Section" & i)
Set rng4 = ActiveSheet.Range("TBLCOL" & i)

rng3.SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:=CStr(rng4.Address)
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).SeriesColor.ThemeColor = 5
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).SeriesColor.TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Negative.Color.ThemeColor = 6
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Negative.Color.TintAndShade = 0
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Markers.Color.ThemeColor = 5
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Markers.Color.TintAndShade = - _
    0.499984740745262
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Highpoint.Color.ThemeColor = 5
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Highpoint.Color.TintAndShade = 0
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Lowpoint.Color.ThemeColor = 5
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Lowpoint.Color.TintAndShade = 0
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Firstpoint.Color.ThemeColor = 5
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Firstpoint.Color.TintAndShade = _
    0.399975585192419
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Lastpoint.Color.ThemeColor = 5
Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Lastpoint.Color.TintAndShade = _
    0.399975585192419
End Sub>
```

I'm using i=3 as this is the foundation for a loop that I will create. I have already created the code that goes through every table and creates one merged cell 2 columns to the right of my Table, Names the merged Cell as "Section" & i. And then finds the 3rd data column in my Table and names it "TBLCOL" & i.

This is the last piece to the puzzle- any feedback would be much appreciated. The above code returns the global failure error message. I know that corresponds to the variable reference but am unable to resolve on my own.

*Edit: Modified for first comment and added formatting gathered during "Record Macro"*

Comment: `rng3.SparkLineGroups.Add ...` since rng3 is already a Range object.

Comment: `rng3.SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:=CStr(rng4.Address)`  Gives me an error of "Method 'Add' of object 'SparklineGroups' failed"

Comment: Have you debugged the code with breakpoints to see where the actual error occurs, and to check if the variables you have used up until then contains the expected values?

Also from what I remember, merged cells are rather poorly implemented and don't always behave the way you would expect.

Comment: @johankr Yes, I've debugged the code and the reference to rng3 and rng4 both work until I enter the sparkline code. And on top of that, I'm using MAC Excel 2016- not sure if that changes the necessary range references.

Comment: I get the below code sample to work (with and without the formatting) so there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code iteself.

`Sub AddSparkline()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim rng4 As Range
 
    i = 3
    Set rng3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Section" & i)
    Set rng4 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("TBLCOL" & i)
    
    rng3.SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkColumn, SourceData:=CStr(rng4.Address)
End Sub`

Can't think of any data in the range that could create a problem either.

Comment: @johankr Just tried that exact code and am getting this error: (Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Add' of object 'SparklineGroups' failed.) Wondering if MAC Excel 2016 is the culprit?

Comment: I think it is the merged cells that is causing the problem. Try adding the sparkline somewhere else and see if that works.

Comment: Or try unmerging the cells first, and see what happens. I managed to add sparklines to a merged cell though, so that can't be the whole story either way though.

Comment: It is the merged cell- just tried it without the merged cell and it worked. Okay back to the drawing board. Thanks for the pointers.